# Joining table only once in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm sure this is very basic, but I've hit a brick wall. First post here, long time reader.

I've got two tables, one is a list of customers, one is a list of their activity by month. For some unknown reason, some of the data in the activity column is duplicated and it's causing me errors when calculating totals.  Is there a way for me to only join the data in the activity table once?

E.g the customer table:

| CustID | AccountNo |
| --- | --- |
| 331 | AccountNo1 |
| 332 | AccountNo2 |
| 333 | AccountNo2 |
| 334 | AccountNo2 |

The activity table looks like this:

| CustID | ActivityID | Month | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 331 | 331133 | Jan-21 | £30 |
| 332 | 331101 | Jan-21 | £10 |
| 332 | 331121 | Feb-21 | £40 |
| 332 | 331196 | Feb-21 | £40 |
| 332 | 331141 | Mar-21 | £40 |
| 333 | 331120 | Feb-21 | £20 |
| 334 | 331119 | Mar-21 | £20 |

You will see there are two rows for customer 332 for Feb-21 with the same sales amount. Total sales for customer 332 are £90 not £130. How do I tell the JOIN to ignore multiple rows for a particular month if duplicated?

At the moment I'm doing a basic:

`JOIN Activity AC (NOLOCK) ON C.CUSTID = AC.CUSTID`

Obviously moving forward the activity table needs fixing but I'm hoping for a quick win!

Sorry if this is basic!
Mark

Comment: In your question, can you also add the exact expected result?

Comment: Which columns will identify a duplicate? I assume they should be (`CustID`, `Month-without-day`, `Sales`) but you are excluding (`ActivityID`).

Comment: Use subquery which will group by customer and month, and summarize the money, collapsing a lot of rows into one. Then join.

Comment: PS. MySQL does not know the word NOLOCK. Maybe you use SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is:

```
select c.*, a.*
from customer c left join
     (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by custid, month order by amount) as seqnum
      from activity a
     ) a
     on c.custid = a.custid and c.seqnum = 1;
```

It is unclear if the amounts need to be the same for the duplication.  If so, include `amount` in the `partition by`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. No doubt this is because I simplified the table to make it easier, but I'm getting "'DP' has more columns than were specified in the column list." the actual table I am using has about 40/45 columns.